# Recording issue in fiddler of iOS native application with https

Tags: ios, ssl, native, fiddler

I want to record web requests using fiddler of an iOS7 native app which using https protocol (with trusted certificates) to communicate with server.
 I could able to record the requests and after **Https decryption option disabled** and its worked fine. When **Https decryption option enabled**  app shows invalid/untrusted certifificate alert and cannot proceed even after installing fiddler certificate in iOS.

Question is,

Is there any way to record Https request/response of iOS7 app using fiddler by imitating any other certificate as trusted certificate or anyother way to do that? any suggestions?  any other tools? I got another solution from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478842/how-can-i-import-fiddler-generated-certificate-to-ios-device) but it was not worked.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [Fiddler Certificate Maker add-on](http://fiddler2.com/r/?FiddlerCertMaker) to generate certificates that iOS is willing to trust.

See http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/12-12-21/using-fiddler-with-apple-ios-devices for more information.

Also keep in mind that some iOS applications (like the AppStore) use a technique called "Certificate Pinning" which means that you cannot decrypt their traffic seamlessly unless you jailbreak the device.

Comment: Thanks **Eric** let me try and will be back with comments.

Comment: Hi,I have done all the previous settings in the " http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/12-12-21/using-fiddler-with-apple-ios-devices" but my iPhone is unable to open the link "http://ipv4.fiddler:8888/" in iOS 8.Can you please suggest me what could be wrong.

Comment: @Imran: oh brother, they are given the "demo" link, you need to use your own fiddler IP address, eg: http://192.168.100.99:8888/ to hit the same. :)